# Kill all processes related to an application

Tags: linux, shell, process, kill

I have two processes that are temporarily spawned and I need to kill them. Here are the processes from `ps aux`

```
david  38329   0.0  5.0  3916476 104624 s002  S    11:33AM   0:17.43 /Applications/Firefox.a
david  38319   0.0  0.0  2442472   1028 s002  S    11:33AM   0:00.10 Xvfb -br -screen 0 800x
david  38268   0.0  0.2  3012352   4960   ??  S    11:02AM   0:00.24 /System/Library/Framewo
david  38261   0.0  3.4  3913364  70724 s002  S    11:02AM   0:08.51 /Applications/Firefox.a
```

How would I kill all processes that are either `Xvfb` or `Firefox` ?

**Update:** I was able to use `$ sudo killall Xvfb` to kill that process, but am still having trouble doing the same with Firefox:

```
davids-Mac-mini:financials david$ ps aux|grep firefox
david          /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -foreground
david          /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -foreground
david          grep firefox
davids-Mac-mini:financials david$ sudo killall firefox
No matching processes were found
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to do it by name:

```
killall firefox
```

If you want to kill a specific process, e.g. the first Firefox instance:

```
kill 38329
```

and if the process doesn't want to go, you can use:

```
kill -KILL 38261
```

There should be no way for a program to keep the OS from terminating it *RIGHT NOW*.

**Update:** To see a list of all available process names for the `killall` command, you can use:

```
ps -axco command | sort | uniq
```

Comment: $ sudo killall Firefox
    No matching processes were found

Comment: Corrected to `killall firefox`, the process that is actually running is the `firefox` binary inside the Firefox.app bundle.

Comment: Please see update in question.

Comment: `killall firefox-bin` should work for you. At least Firefox 13 uses `firefox` as process name.

Answer (score 6):

You could do

```
kill `pgrep Xvfb` `pgrep Firefox`
```

You can add -f to search the entire command, in case it doesn't find it without the -f.

```
pgrep -f Firefox
```

There is also pkill which takes the same input as pgrep

```
pkill Xvfb; pkill -f Firefox;
```

Comment: I don't have pkill or pkill on my machine. How would I do the same with `killall` ?

Answer (score 0):

This function kills all processes related to an application. You can call it like this: `killapp chrome`

```
killapp () {
    processes=($(pidof $1))
    for pid in $processes
        do 
            kill -9 $pid
        done
    }
```

If you are in macos and don't have `pidof` installed you can install it with `brew` or use `pgrep` instead.

I think `pidof` works best since it finds **all** processes related to a given application whereas it is not always the case with `pgrep`.